# Nesting web applications in IIS 7 and keeping child apps from inheriting Parent web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have am trying to use the location attribute to to set inheritInChildApplications = false
so that I can nest a second application under an existing IIS application without config conflicts.

There's a problem however. The second application www.mydomain.com/SecondApp/home will load but now all pages from the Parent application will not load i.e. www.mydomain.com/aboutus throws an exception because the HttpHandlers were not loaded.

How can I get the httpHandlers to load on the subpages of the parent site but not in the second application?

I've been using location as follows:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
        <!-- Stuff -->
        <httpHandlers>
            Blah
        </httpHandlers>  
    </system.web>
 </location>




<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <!-- Stuff -->
            <handlers>
                Blah
            </handlers>  
        </system.webServer>
     </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I ended up fixing the solution was to remove the offending handlers, modules, extensions and assemblies from the child config and not using location. i.e.:

```
<httpHandlers>
     <remove name="offendingHttphandler" />
     Rest of the good handlers
</httpHandlers>
```

P.S. just pray that the nested application does not a different application pool that uses a different pipeline or version of .NET. Just pray. Otherwise this solution will not work.